# How to properly access data from the django database?

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite, web-frameworks

I have been trying to generate a list of books that are not been reviewed by a user, ie the books for which he/she has not written a review for. Here are the essential details from my **models.py**:

```
class book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    genre_name = models.IntegerField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    img = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class reviews(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    bookid = models.IntegerField()
    review = models.CharField(max_length=750)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So, I have been trying to first get the books that the user has reviewed something like this:

```
books1 = reviews.objects.filter(name=username)
```

And to get the database of the books, I am doing the following:

```
allb = book.objects.all()
```

Initially, I just randomly generated 5 numbers in the `range(1,132)` and stored them in a array `randb`, something like this:

```
randb = []
for i in range(0,5):
    randb.append(randint(1,132))
```

And then later linking those generated numbers to the book database that I retrieved in `allb` in the HTML part.

My main concern is when I do that, I end up getting the books which are already reviewed by the user, simply because I have not given any condition for that.

**Note: I want to retrieve only those book ids which are not been reviewed by the user.**

Further, I tried doing the following in order to filter it out:

```
books1 = reviews.objects.filter(name=username)
allb = book.objects.all()
randb = []
reviewed_books = books1.bookid /*I get error in this line: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'bookid'*/
count = 0
for i in range(0,132):
    if i not in reviewed_books
        randb.append(randint(1,132))
        count = count + 1
    if count == 5
        break
```

I don't know how to make that line (the commented line in the above code) work. Need suggestions and some code snippet to make my code work.

Thank you in advance :)

**EDIT:** (I forgot the colons ':' after if statements)

```
books1 = reviews.objects.filter(name=username)
allb = book.objects.all()
randb = []
reviewed_books = books1.bookid /*I get error in this line: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'bookid'*/
count = 0
for i in range(0,132):
    if i not in reviewed_books:
        randb.append(randint(1,132))
        count = count + 1
    if count == 5:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try finding all books and then from that result, exclude books that have already been reviewed by the user:

```
book.objects.exclude(id__in=reviews.objects.filter(name=username).values_list('id', flat=True)
```